# Few Debug Points are not working in Eclipse in Mac

Tags: eclipse

In one of the projects in my Eclipse, certain debug point are being skipped by Eclipse. This is happening in one of the classes of the project. The class and its methods are being called but while debugging, the debug points are not working in this class. I am using Mac machine. Tried same project in Windows, it is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any [trigger point](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/breakpoints/ref-triggerpoint_option.htm) that need to be hit first? Or maybe the breakpoint has a condition that does not apply. Please show your _Breakpoints_ view and details about the breakpoint that does not work.

Comment: I updated my Eclipse and Java version and then cleaned the project. They are working now. Thanks @howlger